# 3n+1 Programming Challenge in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

The 3n+1 challenge is quite popular and can be found [here](http://www.programming-challenges.com/pg.php?page=downloadproblem&probid=110101&format=html)

I've created a solution in python below and also here on [github](https://github.com/webiken/algorithms/blob/master/3n%2B1/solution.py)

```
def solution(i, j):
    count = toRtn = 1
    for n in xrange(i, j+1):
        count = 1
        while n != 1:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                n = n/2
            else:
                n = (3 * n) + 1
            count += 1
        toRtn = max(toRtn, count)
    return toRtn

print solution(100, 200)
print solution(201, 210)
```

I have several questions:

1. Can and should this be re-written as a recursion?  Whould that improve efficiency?
2. How can I calculate the complexity of this function?
3. Is there an online judge for Python for those challenges?

Comment: Recursion is (almost?) never the most efficient solution, if straightforward iterative approaches exist. Also, it's frowned upon to ask three questions in one question.

Comment: This 'challenge' is known as the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: I accept the -1 for asking three question in one, but why the other -1?

Comment: @SamHammamy Yeah Im looking for that answer actually. I got -4 for I just wrote Python as python. Nice users ha :-)

Comment: Recursion is tricky with Python because there is always a limit on how many times a function is allowed to call itself without returning. By default, this limit is 1000. So, if you enter a number that will produce a chain longer than 1000, you'll get an error.

Comment: @ajcr - you can alter the maximum recursion depth quite easily.

Comment: @will how can that be done?

Comment: @will: yes, but the point is that you cannot set it infinitely high. Sooner or later, however high it's set, you might input a number that will exceed it. There's some discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/maximum-recursion-depth) on why it's not sensible to set it too high.

Comment: No you can't. You can mimic [unlimited recursion using stackless python](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stackless.html). You can also considerably reduce the amount of recursision needed by using a cache / momoizing (i'm still not a fan of that ridiculous word), as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: @ajcr But yes, i do agree with the sentiment, it's essentially using the language for something it wasn't designed for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Strictly speaking recursion itself can't optimize itself. Recursion is not about optimization, but about clarity when needed. However you could use recursion with memoization to boost the performance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

2) Complexity of the function sum of the complexity of each of its statements. So to calculate the whole complexity you should construct a table of two columns for each line: [Number of times called], [Complexity] and sum up each of the row. Let's look at the following code:

```
 def print_N_times(N):
    print "------"        #Line1
    for i in range(0,N):  #Line2
        print "easy"      #Line3
    print "------"        #Line4
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| Line number | Number of times executed | Complexity | 
|  Line 1     |        1                 |     1      |
|  Line 2     |        N+1               |     1      |
|  Line 3     |        N                 |     1      |
|  Line 4     |        1                 |     1      |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

(Here 1 is as a replacement for constant complexity)

So by multiplying each column and summing them up:

1*1 + (N+1)*1 + N*1 + 1*1 = 2*N + 3 = O(N), so this function has linear complexity.

3) There're a lot of judges, but spoj.pl accepts variety of programming languages:

http://www.spoj.com/problems/PROBTRES/

Edit: Correctly noted in comments that for 3n+1 problem you don't know each value of the [Number of times of executed] column, or whether the function will be finished ever. For more info see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: But if it can't be proven that it will halt how can it have O(N) complexity

Comment: @AnuragUniyal Really? It seems you're blindly replacing concrete with general. It the same as you would say "That's an NP-hard problem" by looking at 2SAT.

Comment: @manzur: Yes, really.  You can't establish how many times the loop will execute, because sometimes n *increases* (for example, n=3).  In fact, its a pretty famous open problem whether or not the function is defined for all n.

Comment: @ScottHunter sure, but my evaluation is for the function I wrote, not for 3n+1.

Comment: @manzur: But your technique does not apply to this problem, and thus is not appropriate in an answer to it.

Comment: also recursion can only add readability, iterative version can be cached for better performance

Comment: @AnuragUniyal a smart compiler will turn tail recursion into iteration automatically. No need to worry.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a recursive method to calculate `3n+1`

```
def threen(n):
    if n ==1:
        return 1
    if n%2 == 0:
        n = n/2
    else:
        n = 3*n+1
    return threen(n)+1
```

To avoid calculating same numbers twice you can cache values

```
cache = {}
def threen(n):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    if n ==1:
        return 1
    orig = n
    if n%2 == 0:
        n = n/2
    else:
        n = 3*n+1
    count = threen(n)+1
    cache[orig] = count
    return count
```

Now you can use this in a loop

```
def max_threen(i, j):
    max3n = 0
    for n in xrange(i, j+1):
        max3n= max(threen(n), max3n)
    print i, j, max3n

max_threen(100,201)
```

Now you can compare this with your version :), it may consume a lot of memory but could be faster for certain ranges, obviously a non recursive method would be faster if you are caching values, but recursion is fun and more readable, but in anycase iterative version will be faster with caching (not tested)

```
cache = {}
def solution(i, j):
    count = toRtn = 1
    for n in xrange(i, j+1):
        count = 1
        orig = n
        if n in cache:
            count = cache[n]
        else:
            while n != 1:
                if n % 2 == 0:
                    n = n/2
                else:
                    n = (3 * n) + 1
                count += 1

            cache[orig] = count
        toRtn = max(toRtn, count)
    return toRtn
```

Comment: So its "obviously" not faster, but its fun...got it.

Comment: @ScottHunter faster than OP's version :)

Comment: In certain cases, recursion is much easier to read, as in the factorial example for instance.  The question wasn't fun vs not-fun, but rather speed and readability

Comment: "Would that improve efficiency?" was the original question; this "answer" brought in the question of fun (in a playful way, but still).

Answer (score 0):

1. No and no; recursion is rarely (if ever) used for better performance.
2. You can't, since it hasn't even been established that it will return for all values of `n`.  (Nobody has found one that it *doesn't* return for, but no one has proved that there isn't one, either.)
3. Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Disagreed on 1.  With this problem, recursion is an opportunity to use memoization, which can provide a significant speedup when you avoid redoing work.  So it is possible for recursion to improve efficiency, particularly if you're doing a wide range.  That said, rewriting a recursive version to an iterative form will probably be a speedup.

Comment: And memoization can't be done w/o recursion because...?

Comment: @ScottHunter, The usual meaning of memoization is based around function calls. Since there is only one function call without recursion, memoization won't help. You can (and should) use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) though

Comment: A simple cache would do the job nicely.

Comment: @ScottHunter I find it easier to initially implement memoization with recursion.  But I agree that rewriting that version iteratively would be likely to improve performance.